# Local storage of browser not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I'm trying to use the local storage of a browser to store an array, but it's not working properly. When I'm testing it out it's return "null" for both indexes of the array for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
window.localStorage.clear();
var requesterID = "ABC";
var title = "title";

if (window.localStorage.getItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek") == null) {
window.localStorage.setItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek", JSON.stringify(["placeHolder1"]));
} //end of if (window.localStorage.getItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek") == null)

window.localStorage.setItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek", JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek")).push(requesterID+title)));
var tempArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek"));

console.log(tempArray[0]);
console.log(tempArray[1]);
```

**Expected Result:**

```
placeHolder1
ABCtitle
```

**Actual Result:**

```
null
null
```

Comment: I just tested and It worked here. If possible, could you provide more details?

Comment: I just pasted your code into jsfiddle, and got it to print the expected result.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: @A.Meshu Google Chrome. With TamperMonkey.

Comment: @A.Meshu I used window.localStorage.clear() and now it's working. -.-

Comment: If you run `window.localStorage.getItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek")` in devtools script console, is a non-null value returned?

Comment: @frosty this was exactly what i wanted to offer... glad it works (:

Comment: @A.Meshu I edited the code, and I'm trying to push an array into it, and it's returning null again, Can you take a look, please?

Comment: `tempArray` is not an array, but the value `2`, which is the length of the array (what `push` returns), as @Cristian mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `Array.prototype.push` adds the element to the array, and **returns the new length of the array**, as you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

You can split your function:

```
const array = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek"));
array.push(requesterID+title);
const stringifiedArray = JSON.stringify(array);

window.localStorage.setItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek", stringifiedArray);
```

Or you can use `Array.prototype.concat` in place of `push`:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek", JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("alreadyGotLastForAWeek")).concat([requesterID+title])));
```

Comment: Ohhh. concat is perfect for this.

Comment: `concat` works as a charm and it's perfect if you don't want to modify the original array (it returns a new array without changing the existing). But for sake of readibility, I advise the first solution